# Get string from mail body via regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, regex, email

I don't understand how to correctly get a string from mail body

Input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
http://link.com/tace/1232BW
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore ma
```

Output:

```
http://link.com/tace/1232BW
```

There is what I tried :

```
 let localLink = recipientMessage.html.body.match((http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?);
```

Comment: @AKSingh Yes, whole link - ```http://link.com/tace/1232BW```

Comment: The web developer console in your web browser should be yelling at you about errors. Check out those errors and try this instead `let localLink = recipientMessage.html.body.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/);`

Comment: Quite frankly your regex can be just `/(https?|s?ftp):\/\/\S+/` unless you're worried about validating the URL as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit the question as "*How to extract a valid URL from a multiline string*"

You can see (and run) the script below a regular expression that will match all the URLs within the string:

```js
const body = `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
ftp://user:pass@www.link.com/tace/1232BW/lala.js
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
http://www.link.com/tace/1232BW/index.php?qs=val#name
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
https://other.link.com/tace/1232BW
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
`
const regexp = /(((?:(?:https?|ftp):(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[+~%/.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.!/\\\w]*))?)/g
const matches = body.match(regexp)
console.log({ matches })
```

Comment: thanks a lot! and how can I get and copy from array "matches" "http://www.link.com/tace/1232BW/index.php?qs=val#name" and put it in new variable?

Answer (score 0):

There you go: https://regex101.com/r/0imTMr/1

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?
```

Test it like this

```
let regex = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?/;
let localLink = recipientMessage.html.body.match(regex))
```